# 2 submit buttons 1 form consequences

Tags: php, html, forms, button, submit

What are the consequences or repercussions about putting 2 submit buttons in 1 form depending of the browser or getting the information with the $_POST in the other page or there's nothing wrong with that?

So,this is just an example, i would like to know if there is any inconvenient or why its recommended(mandatory) to use just one button per form

Comment: Why do you need two submit buttons?

Comment: i'm not using it right now and i know how to get it in the other page. but i would like to know if there is any inconvenient or why its recommended(mandatory) to use just one button per form

Answer (score 0):

Two submit buttons will not make any issue, if both have different names.

Comment: ok thanks, but ,i would like to know if there is any inconvenient or why its recommended(mandatory) to use just one button per form

Comment: there is nothing like mandatory that you have to use a single submit button. if you put 2 submit buttons it, will still work without any problems. i don't see any inconvenience cause by this

Answer (score 0):

Print all indexs of `$_POST` by `print_r($_POST);` And check for  Form input names in it!

By this method you can find result of this problem! not fix it!!!

Please complete your question And put on your source in this question or in jsfiddle.net!

Comment: thanks, i'm not having any issue but, i would like to know if there is any inconvenient or why its recommended(mandatory) to use just one button per form

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory to use only one submit button per one form. If you keep two or more submit button in one form, they do the same thing, submitting a page. So it does not make any changes.